# Having problems with Events with PrimeFaces 5

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, event-handling

I am using PrimeFaces 5.  Trying to learn it.
I am working on this particular screen for almost 3 days and had no progress.

I read the showcase of Primefaces lots of times, but everything seems to be in order.  It is possible that I am addicted to my code and can not see the answer, but it seems to be all liked because it is all associated with events, or so it seems.

Problems:
 - My DropDown (selectOneMenu) does not respond to click events to show its options;
 - The arrows that do the paging of my search results does not respond to click as well;
 - The search button does not respond after the first search;
 - The View buttons does not displays the dialog;
 - The growl component is also not recieving updates;

I am supplying the link to download the sourcecode here
- https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5784798/par.7z

Comment: You have a lot of script and bootstrap including, to me everything looks rather non-standard. Did you follow a tutorial for the bootstrap? Here's one: http://blog.hatemalimam.com/jsf-and-twitter-bootstrap-integration/. PF uses themeroller so its not standard to use bootstrap. Also you have included jquery manually, PF includes it by itself so might give problems. If removing that alone dont help I'd start with something much simpler and get it working, then adding stuff

Comment: Yes, I made a clean up and removed those scripts.  Now I have less problems to solve.  I updated the code.  Now the problems are reduced to:
- Result page buttons does not change the page results;
- When I select a registry and click View the dialog shows up empty instead of show the registry details.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5784798/par.7z

Answer (score 0):

Here it is the form working

```
<h:form id="formularioResultadoUsuario">
<p:dataTable var="usuario"
value="#{adiminstraUsuarioView.lazyUsuarioDataModel}"
paginator="true" rows="10"
paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" rowKey="#{usuario.id}"
selectionMode="single"
selection="#{adiminstraUsuarioView.selectedUsuario}"
id="usuarioTable" lazy="true">
<p:ajax event="rowSelect"
listener="#{adiminstraUsuarioView.onRowSelect}"
update=":formularioResultadoUsuario:usuarioDetail"
oncomplete="PF('usuarioDialog').show()" />
<p:column headerText="Id" sortBy="#{usuario.id}"
filterBy="#{usuario.id}">
<h:outputText value="#{usuario.id}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Nome" sortBy="#{usuario.nome}"
filterBy="#{usuario.nome}">
<h:outputText value="#{usuario.nome}" />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Grupo" sortBy="#{usuario.grupo}"
filterBy="#{usuario.grupo}">
<h:outputText value="#{usuario.grupo}" />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Role" sortBy="#{usuario.role}"
filterBy="#{usuario.role}">
<h:outputText value="#{usuario.role}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Sistema" sortBy="#{usuario.sistema}"
filterBy="#{usuario.sistema}">
<h:outputText value="#{usuario.sistema}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Subsistema" sortBy="#{usuario.subsistema}"
filterBy="#{usuario.subsistema}">
<h:outputText value="#{usuario.subsistema}" />
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<p:dialog header="Car Detail" widgetVar="usuarioDialog" modal="true"
showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
<p:outputPanel id="usuarioDetail" style="text-align:center;">
<p:panelGrid columns="2"
rendered="#{not empty adiminstraUsuarioView.selectedUsuario}"
columnClasses="label,value">
<h:outputText value="Id:" />
<h:outputText value="#{adiminstraUsuarioView.selectedUsuario.id}" />

<h:outputText value="Nome" />
<h:outputText
value="#{adiminstraUsuarioView.selectedUsuario.nome}" />

<h:outputText value="Grupo:" />
<h:outputText
value="#{adiminstraUsuarioView.selectedUsuario.grupo}" />

<h:outputText value="Role:" />
<h:outputText
value="#{adiminstraUsuarioView.selectedUsuario.role}" />

<h:outputText value="Sistema:" />
<h:outputText
value="#{adiminstraUsuarioView.selectedUsuario.sistema}" />

<h:outputText value="Subsistema:" />
<h:outputText
value="#{adiminstraUsuarioView.selectedUsuario.subsistema}" />

</p:panelGrid>
</p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
</h:form>
```